# d3 bind element to data points / data values

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-binding, element

I think I'm missing some concepts in data binding. I don't have an actual data but let's say data looks like this:

```
name, value
James, 10
Nancy, 20
Amber, 30
Mike, 40
Julian, 50
```

The value represents fruit sales for example :)

Usual way to visualise it could be probably bar chart. The code could look like this - given that all other settings like svg etc are already made) :

```
svg.selectAll(rect)
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append(rect)
    .attr("x", function(d, i) { return i; })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return d.value; })
    .attr("width", 10)
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - d.value; });
```

I understand it binds bars for Each data point (each person) and the value would be projected as bar height.

***But I'd like to make rectangles as many as their sales***. For example, 10 rects for James, 20 rects for Nancy etc.

I thought it may need iteration for value to make as many as rects in theory but cannot find how to make it in technique. Could anyone let me know?

If this way of thinking is not common way in js/d3, then would you mind letting me know what would be natural way to make or/and bind elements to data values?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

Fill in the attribute callbacks yourself.

Maybe you need `d3.select(this.parentNode).datum()`

```
var gbars = svg.selectAll("g.bar")
   .data(data)
   .enter()
   .attr("class", "bar");

gbars.selectAll("rect")
     .data(d => d3.range(d.value) )
     .enter()
     .append("rect")
     .attr("x", function(d, i) { return ****; })
     .attr("y", function(d, i) { return ****; })
     .attr("width", 10)
     .attr("height", function(d, i) { return ****; });
```